# Finding two pairs of numbers such that their products absolute difference is minimized

Tags: c++, algorithm

**Question:**

> Given an integer num, find the closest two integers in absolute difference whose product equals num + 1 or num + 2.
>
> Return the two integers in any order.

I tried this:

```
vector<int> closestDivisors(int num) {
    
    if(num == 1)
        return {1,2};
    int first = num + 1, second = num + 2;
    std::vector<int> result(2);        
    auto vec1 = properDivisors(first);
    auto vec2 = properDivisors(second);
    std::map<int, std::pair<int,int>> m;
    int min_k1 = INT_MAX;
    for(auto it1 : vec1)
    {
        for(auto it2 : vec1)
        {
            if (it1 * it2 == first)
            {
                min_k1 = abs(it1-it2);
                m[min_k1] = {it1, it2};
            }
        }
    }
    
    int min_k2 = INT_MAX;
    for(auto it1 : vec2)
    {
        for(auto it2 : vec2)
        {
            if (it1 * it2 == second)
            {
                min_k2 = abs(it1-it2);
                m[min_k2] = {it1, it2};
            }
        }
    }

    for(auto it : m)
    {
        result[0] = it.second.first;
        result[1] = it.second.second;
        if(result.size() == 2)
            break;
    }
    
    
    

    return result;
}


std::vector<long long> properDivisors(int number) {
   std::vector<long long> divisors ;
   for ( int i = 1 ; i < number / 2 + 1 ; i++ )
      if ( number % i == 0 )
     divisors.push_back( i ) ;
   return divisors ;
}
```

But I keep getting Time Limit Exceeded. Is there a more efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: I find the problem statement very ambiguous, what do they mean by closest two numbers in absolute value? That statement can be interpreted multiple ways...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of vectors is probably going to make it much slower than it needs to be. I would approach it as follows.

Set `lo` to `1` and `hi` to `num + 1`. This is the starting point for getting two integers that multiply out to one of the desired values (closer together then `1` and `num + 2` so you can ignore that possibility).

Then simply move `lo` and `hi` toward each other (until they cross) checking the product to see if it's equal to a desired value. The fact that the two numbers are approaching means that any later success will have them closer together than the earlier ones.

The only tricky bit is how the numbers approach each other but this is simpler than you think. If the product is less than `num + 1`, decreasing `hi` will mean it gets *further* away from a desired value so you need to increase `lo` in that case.

On the other hand, the product being greater than `num + 2` means you should decrease `hi` (increasing `lo` would move the product higher, hence further away from a desired value).

If it's equal to `num + 1` or `num + 2`, you can choose either option. The reason it doesn't matter is because the absolute difference between `lo + 1` and `hi` is the same as that between `lo` and `hi -1`<sup>(a)</sup>.

---

For example, here's a Python program that shows it in action:

```
num = int(input("Number: "))
lo = 1
hi = num + 1
found = None
while lo <= hi: # Make this '<' if numbers must be different.
    prod = lo * hi
    if prod == num + 1 or prod == num + 2:
        found = (lo, hi)
        mark = ' *'
    else:
        mark = ""
    print(f"Low = {lo}, high = {hi}, product = {prod}{mark}")
    if prod < num + 1:
        lo += 1
    else:
        hi -= 1
print(found)
```

Along with a couple of runs:

```
Number: 3
Low = 1, high = 4, product = 4 *
Low = 1, high = 3, product = 3
Low = 2, high = 3, product = 6
Low = 2, high = 2, product = 4 *
(2, 2)

Number: 10
Low = 1, high = 11, product = 11 *
Low = 1, high = 10, product = 10
Low = 2, high = 10, product = 20
Low = 2, high = 9, product = 18
Low = 2, high = 8, product = 16
Low = 2, high = 7, product = 14
Low = 2, high = 6, product = 12 *
Low = 2, high = 5, product = 10
Low = 3, high = 5, product = 15
Low = 3, high = 4, product = 12 *
Low = 3, high = 3, product = 9
(3, 4)

Number: 100
Low = 1, high = 101, product = 101 *
Low = 1, high = 100, product = 100
Low = 2, high = 100, product = 200
Low = 2, high = 99, product = 198
: : : (lots of stuff irrelevant to final result)
Low = 6, high = 18, product = 108
Low = 6, high = 17, product = 102 *
Low = 6, high = 16, product = 96
Low = 7, high = 16, product = 112
Low = 7, high = 15, product = 105
Low = 7, high = 14, product = 98
Low = 8, high = 14, product = 112
Low = 8, high = 13, product = 104
Low = 8, high = 12, product = 96
Low = 9, high = 12, product = 108
Low = 9, high = 11, product = 99
Low = 10, high = 11, product = 110
Low = 10, high = 10, product = 100
(6, 17)
```

---

As pointed out in a comment, this only handles positive inputs. You can cater for negative inputs as well by changing:

```
lo = 1
hi = num + 1
```

to:

```
lo = -num - 1
hi = num + 1
if lo > hi:
    (lo, hi) = (hi, lo)
```

This brackets the positive *and* negative realms for solutions, adding a little extra time but still pretty fast.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> I'm only 99.99% sure of my mathematics here so, if anyone can provide a counter example, I'll be happy to edit the answer (or even delete it, if I can't fix it though any problems that exist are *probably* going to be found in the edge cases so will likely be fixable with some simple pre-checks). Let me know.

Comment: any chance you can right this logic in a language of your choice?

Comment: Does it work for negative numbers? (I haven't checked, but that's the obvious unchecked edge case)

Comment: I suspect this can be done far more efficiently by starting at `sqrt(num)` and working **outwards**

Comment: @Donnie: good point. You can handle negative numbers with initialising `lo = -num - 1`, `hi = num + 1`, `if lo > hi: (lo, hi) = (hi, lo)`. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Rather than starting with lo = 1 and hi = num + 1 and moving lo and hi toward each other, you'll get better performance by starting with lo ≈ hi ≈ √num and moving lo and hi away from each other. That way, you can exit as soon as you find a solution.

Comment: @paxdiablo ... starting at the `sqrt` takes far **fewer** iterations

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code in c++.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void print_vector(vector<auto> v){
   cout << "[";
   for(int i = 0; i<v.size(); i++){
       if(v.size() - i == 1) {
           cout << v[i];
       } else {
          cout << v[i] << ", ";
       }
   }
   cout << "]"<<endl;
}
class Solution {
public:
   vector <int> getDiv(int x){
      int diff = INT_MAX;
      vector <int> ret(2);
      for(int i = 1; i * i <= x; i++){
         if(x % i == 0){
            int a = i;
            int b = x / i;
            int newDiff = abs(a - b);
            if(newDiff < diff){
               diff = newDiff;
               ret[0] = a;
               ret[1] = b;
            }
         }
      }
      return ret;
   }
   vector<int> closestDivisors(int num) {
      vector <int> op1 = getDiv(num + 1);
      vector <int> op2 = getDiv(num + 2);
      return abs(op1[0] - op1[1]) <= abs(op2[0] - op2[1]) ? op1 : op2;
   }
};
main(){
   Solution ob;
   print_vector(ob.closestDivisors(8));
}

// Output [3,3]
```

[You can run the above code here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php)

[Reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/closest-divisors-in-cplusplus).

Code in Javascript.

```
let num = 8; //Input

function getFactors(num) {
  let factors = [1];
  for (let i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      factors.push(i);
      factors.push(num / i);
    }
  }
  factors.push(num);
  return factors;
}

(function getSmallAbsDiff() {
  const factorsNplusOne = getFactors(num + 1).sort((a, b) => a - b);
  const factorsNplusTwo = getFactors(num + 2).sort((a, b) => a - b);

  const minOne = factorsNplusOne[factorsNplusOne.length / 2 - 1];
  const maxOne = factorsNplusOne[factorsNplusOne.length / 2];
  const minTwo = factorsNplusTwo[factorsNplusTwo.length / 2 - 1];
  const maxTwo = factorsNplusTwo[factorsNplusTwo.length / 2];

  maxOne - minOne < maxTwo - minTwo ? console.log(`[${maxOne}, ${minOne}]`) : console.log(`[${maxTwo}, ${minTwo}]`); // Output
})();
```

[Reference](https://codepen.io/abhishek2kr/pen/YzwBOVG)